# How can i display saved text file on list view?

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, io

```
File file = new 
File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), 
"text.txt");
if(file.exists()) 
{
   Toast.makeText(this, "File Exist" + file, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
else{
     Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found" + file, 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I want to display text.txt items on listview

text.txt:

```
1234
0000
abcd
```

i have checked if the file exist or not but i am not able to display the items on listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Scanner to read the components of your file like so:

```
     // creates scanner of that file path
     Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("path here"));
     // read till there aren't elements
     while(fileScanner.hasNext())
     {   // printing whole that next line
         System.out.println(fileScanner.next());
     }
```

This will print the whole line till there are no more lines to read/print

**NOTE** fileScanner.next() is of type String, I am simply printing it to the console for display